# Blackberry Facebook prob: Could not select proper Transport decriptor

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I am using Blackberry Facebook SDK (FacebookBlackBerrySDK-v0.8.25.jar) for facebook integration for my app. I am using the following code.

```
ApplicationSettings as = new ApplicationSettings(NEXT_URL, APPLICATION_ID, APPLICATION_SECRET, PERMISSIONS);
Facebook fb = Facebook.getInstance(as);
User user = fb.getCurrentUser();
```

I have tested the app in simulator of OS 5.0 and device and simulator of OS 6.0. it is working fine. But when I am testing the same in a device of OS 5.0, it is giving "Could not select proper Transport descriptor". What may be the problem behind it? Is it related to the device? How to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the internet using your device?

Comment: Yes, internet is working, I can open webpages from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Download the SDK source code and change the `ConnectionFactory` parameters in  `com.blackberry.util.ui.BrowserScreen`.